# How to access Jira GreenHopper's data from a client application?

Tags: web-services, jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile

I need to access Jira GreenHopper's data from a client application. Is the data exposed through the same Jira SOAP apis or there are other ways of accessing it? Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can access GreenHopper data via the API. Use the [REST API Browser](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2011/11/introducing-the-rest-api-browser-and-the-atlassian-developer-toolbox/) to find a list of all of the REST endpoints and the data you can gather (sprints, rank, boards, etc).

If you have any other questions about GreenHopper or JIRA then [Atlassian Answers](http://answers.atlassian.com) is a great resource.

Thanks,

[Nicholas Muldoon](http://nicholasmuldoon.com)

[@GreenHopperTeam](http://twitter.com/GreenHopperTeam)